# How can I have month and year in x axis, display as number in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

Right now in my highcharts I have x axis displaying dates. The date displayed is in the following format

`30 Nov 2019 10:00`

My settings for x axis

```
          xAxis:{
            type:'datetime',
            title:
            {
              align:'high'
            }, 
            labels: {
              padding: 50,
              format: '{value:%e %b %Y %H:%M}',
              style: {
                fontSize: '10px'
              }
            }
          },
```

How can I have the date displayed as such

`30 11 19 10:00`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the formats shown on the documentation: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts#.dateFormat:

```
      xAxis:{
        type:'datetime',
        title:
        {
          align:'high'
        }, 
        labels: {
          padding: 50,
          format: '{value:%d %m %y %H:%M}',
          style: {
            fontSize: '10px'
          }
        }
      },
```

More generaly, these formats are used widely across many programming languages, and the reference is [PHP's strftime implementation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php).

Comment: Thanks. One last thing. The datetime gets displayed in multiple lines eg `05 new line 05 new line 19` . Is there a way to force it to become `05 05 19` all in one line ? Thanks

Comment: Use unbreakable spaces